# Difference between set vs add when assigning Chef roles to nodes

Tags: chef-infra, knife

Disclaimer: I'm a first time Chef user.

I created a base role I would like to add to a node. What's the difference between the two commands?

```
knife node run_list add <MYNODE> "role[ic_base]"

knife node run_list set <MYNODE> "role[ic_base]"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set will overwrite whatever is there, add will append to the existing run list.